# How can I load different api keys based on a current schema in Objective C/iOS development?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to load my correct intercom API key based on my schema (staging/production)

Here is my current code

```
[Intercom setApiKey:@"xxxx" forAppId:@"xxx"];
```

Calling this at `initWithBundleURL`

Comment: do you added target in your project ?

Comment: if you have added target in your project then you can create "Preprocessor Macros" and after you can differentiate your schema using macros.

Comment: Yes I have all schemes set up but how do I do this via code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

first you have to create macros in your both targets.

select your target --> Build Settings --> Apple LLVM - Preprocessing --> Preprocessing Macros --> create your macro

when you create macro at that time you have to give value of that. so in staging target, give macros name like (e.g. STAGING=1) and in production target, give macros name like (e.g. STAGING=0)

when you run the app of staging target schema at that time staging value is 1 and when you run the app of production target schema at that time staging value is 0.

check below code  :

```
#if STAGING
    [Intercom setApiKey:@"xxxx" forAppId:@"xxx"]; //set your staging api key
#else
    [Intercom setApiKey:@"xxxx" forAppId:@"xxx"]; //set your production api key
#endif
```